# Is there a way to draw a level tree?

Tags: trees

Consider the following expression.

```
expr = {a, {b1, b2}, {c, {d1, d2}}};
```

One can get the levels in an expression as follows:

```
ClearAll[levels];
SetAttributes[levels, {HoldAllComplete}];
levels[expr_] := 
  Column @ Table[Level[expr, {level}, Heads -> True], {level, 0, Depth[expr]-1}];
levels[expr]
```

But when I look at the `TreeForm` of  it `expr`

```
TreeForm[expr]
```

I don't see what I expected: the leaf count for this expression should be 10.

```
LeafCount[expr]
```

One can try to get the true level tree as follows:

```
Graph[
  {
    Sequence @@ (expr\[UndirectedEdge]#& /@ {List, a, {b1, b2}, {c,{d1, d2}}}),
    Sequence @@ (expr[[2]]\[UndirectedEdge]#& /@ {List2, b1, b2}),
    Sequence @@ (expr[[3]]\[UndirectedEdge]#& /@ {List3, c, {d1, d2}}),
    Sequence @@ (expr[[3,2]]\[UndirectedEdge]#& /@ {List4, d1, d2})
  }, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Is there a way to produce this graph for arbitrary expression?

Also, multiple vertices with the same name `List` get joined so I have to rename them to `List1`, `List2`, ..., etc. Is there a way to fix this while keeping the layout of the graph?
`
asically, I want to display  heads at the same level as their parts, which is their true position in the tree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[expr /. List -> (List[List, ##] &)]
```

[image]

```
TreeForm[expr /. List -> (List[List, ##] &)]
```

[image]

```
rules = List @@@ SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[expr /. List -> (List[List, ##] &)];
edges = DirectedEdge @@@ (rules[[All, All, 2]] + 1);
vertices = Property[#2 + 1, {VertexLabels -> #3}] & @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[rules, 1]];

TreeGraph[vertices, edges, ImagePadding -> 40, ImageSize -> 600,  VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach is to use the original expression with `ExpressionToTree` and add new edges:

```
g1 = Graph[SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[{a, {b1, b2}, {c, foo[d1, d2]}}], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabelStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
newedges = # \[DirectedEdge] 
    {Symbol[ToString[Head[First@Last[#]]] <> ToString[#[[2]]]]} & /@ 
   Select[VertexList[g1], Head[#[[1]]] === Symbol &];
VertexReplace[EdgeAdd[g1, newedges], v_ :> Last[v]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the code

```
levelTree[expr_] := Replace[expr, {h_[x___] -> {h, x}}, {0, Infinity}];    
levelTree @ {a, {b1, b2}, {c, {d1, d2}}}
```

which returns

```
{List, a, {List, b1, b2}, {List, c, {List, d1, d2}}}
```

A simple exmaple

```
levelTree[a b + c d]
```

which returns

```
{Plus, {Times, a, b}, {Times, c, d}}
```

I like the lispy variation

```
levelTree[expr_] := Replace[expr, (h : Except[List])[x___] -> {h, x}, {0, Infinity}];
levelTree @ plus[car[{1, 2}], cdr[{3, 4}]]
```

which returns

```
{plus, {car, {1, 2}}, {cdr, {3, 4}}}
```

Given any of these results, you can now use `TreeForm[]` or `ExpressionGraph[]` or some other custom Graph display.