# How can I parametrically generate a hierarchically clustered network?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to create an image to illustrate what a large, hierarchically clustered network looks like. The details of the network don't matter, as long as, when plotted, it clearly shows at least a few levels of hierarchical modularity. The documentation on tools like ClusteringTree and those in the Hierarchical Clustering package suggest that those are data analysis tools which aim to extract clustering structure from existing data. How can I *generate* a hierarchical network ab initio? Thanks!

Comment: How about Generating Random Data and make Tree? `ClusteringTree[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]]` [example picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pAl4U.png)

Comment: is any of these of any help: [TreeGraph construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197938/125), [Is there a way to draw a level tree?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191909/125), [Elegant implementation of factorial tree graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187060/125), [KaryTree](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KaryTree.html), [CompleteKaryTree](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompleteKaryTree.html)?